# Tracking clicks on a Tweet button that has already been rendered using iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

This has been frustrating me for a while..

I'm working on a site where the "Tweet" button is embded via iframe like this:

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?" style="width:110px; height:20px;"></iframe>
```

.  I need a callback function that fires when someone tweets the article on the page.

First problem I noticed is that twttr object was not available. So what I do is dynamically load this:

```
Site.load(window.location.protocol + '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
```

Site.load is our own custom loader function which asynchronously loads a script file.

Then twttr object is available, great!

Now I try binding to the tweet event like this:

```
twttr.events.bind('tweet', myCallbackFunction);
```

I then used the tweet button but the callback function did not fire.

I assumed maybe because the twttr object is available only after the iframe has already rendered, it's not picking up that there's a twitter object on the page.

I tried doing this:

```
twttr.widgets.load()
```

thinking that it would "rescan" the page and register any twitter objects on the page.  But that also did not work.

Note that in this case I have no choice but to leave the iframe as is, instead of doing a better type of embed in the first place.  Keeping that in mind, is there any way I can do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Code? Can you show us a more complete example of what you have tried?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've updated the post with code snippets. I can't disclose the whole page but this should suffice to show the issue I believe